# Android Google Maps V2 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

**I have this in my class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.coffeeandcookies.ushuaiamovil.R;

public class LayMapa2 extends FragmentActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) 
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.lay_mapa2);
        super.onCreate(arg0);
    }
}
```

**This in my xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**This in my manifiest**

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
              android:required="true"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.coffeeandcookies.usuahiamovil.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.coffeeandcookies.usuahiamovil.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="saasadsad" />
```

**And I have google-play-services_lib as library proyect in my workspace and the android-support-v4.jar**

**This is my logcat**

```
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.coffeeandcookies.ushuaiamovil/com.coffeeandcookies.vistas.LayMapa2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1912)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at com.coffeeandcookies.vistas.LayMapa2.onCreate(LayMapa2.java:14)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     ... 11 more
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:577)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4806)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
07-17 11:46:10.945: E/AndroidRuntime(8241):     ... 20 more
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch super.onCreate first, then setContentView.

This is because super.onCreate calls the framework's Activity.onCreate to allocate the resources needed to inflate any layouts. Hence , must be called before inflating any layouts, xml/programmatic.

Comment: I love you maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaan!!!!!!!!!! You're my herooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo!!!!!

Comment: If this answer helped. Click on the green check to accept as asnwer.

Comment: Yes, I'm a few minutes. I can't accept an answer in the first 10 minutes of posted the question

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this :

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

     private GoogleMap map;
     private LatLng ltlng;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer of Bhavesh Patadiya, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18227605/2684720

as you are extending FragmentActivity which indicates you are using Support library v4 compatible with lower version of android. Replace MapFragment with SupportMapFragment inside your xml file. SupportMapFragment is the one to use with the Android Support package. MapFragment is for the native API Level 11 version of fragments.